# Hyphen with multiple adjectives

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

A five-year-old whiskey 
A five year old boy

Should multiple adjectives describing a noun be hyphenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a **compound adjective**.

Examples:
an off-campus apartment
state-of-the-art design
a five-mile-long road
A five-year-old whiskey (or whisky sometimes)
A five-year-old boy

Comment: so the phrase "A five year old boy" that I commonly see is incorrect?

Comment: In US English, you may omit the hyphens in compound adjectives, provided this does not lead to ambiguity. British English is stricter.