# Multi-word Compound Adjectives with Past Participle

Tags: adjectives, compounds

In the sentence:

> The cost overrun was due to a higher-than-budgeted consumption of electricity,

should ***higher-than-budgeted*** be hyphenated?

It seems to me that it should definitely be hyphenated, given that the phrase is a compound adjective that precedes its noun. However, does that change when the last word is a participle?

Comment: You're right, it should be hyphenated. There's no special rule for participles

Comment: No: it's not a compound word but a syntactic construction so there is no need to hyphenate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphenation of adjectives composed of three words.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136088/hyphenation-of-adjectives-composed-of-three-words) Also [three-word compound adjective hyphenation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248439/three-word-compound-adjective-hyphenation) and [Hyphen with multiple adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225308/hyphen-with-multiple-adjectives), among others

Comment: Hyphenation is effectively a ***stylistic choice*** in your exact context. As it happens, two of the first three results returned by a Google Books search for [**a lower than expected score**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+lower+than+expected+score%22) feature hyphens, but scrolling through more results it's obvious that's misleading. Usually that sequence is *not* hyphenated - but unless I was constrained to follow some specific style guide that ruled against such hyphenation, I think I might well include them myself.

Comment: Many style guides advise you to hyphenate numerical adjectives before nouns. Although this isn't a numerical adjective, it's close, and so I'd go with the hyphenation.